# relational algebra and sql

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

Find the name and numbers of those candidates who have achieved one or more final grade between 11  and 16?

```
DEPARTMENT(D#,D-NAME,HEAD-OF-DEPT)
MODULE(M#,M-NAME,M-LEVEL,D#)
CANDIDATE(C#,C-NAME,C-ADDRESS)
RESULT(C#,M#,CW-GRADE,EXAM-GRADE,FINAL-GRADE)
```

I am not understanding the one or more final grade between 11 and 16.

That is the current state of the query:

```
SELECT C#, C_NAME 
  FROM CANDIDATE C, 
       RESULT R 
 WHERE R.C# = C.C# AND 
       FINAL_GRADE BETWEEN 11 AND 16;
```

Comment: Is this your homework for tommorow or what? Show us what you have done so far!

Comment: sql SELECT C#,C_NAME                                                        FROM CANDIDATE C,RESULT R                                              WHERE R.C#  = C.C#                                                      AND FINAL_GRADE BETWEEN 11 AND 16;

Comment: You are close. Good work so far. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short:

```
SELECT C#, C_NAME 
  FROM CANDIDATE C
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM RESULT R 
         WHERE R.C# = C.C# AND 
               FINAL_GRADE BETWEEN 11 AND 16) >= 1;
```

Comment: Sorry but you never mentioned it. The good thing: You just have to translate it into relational algebra.

Answer (score 0):

In the relation / table `RESULT`, there is an attribute / column `FINAL-GRADE`. The value of `FINAL-GRADE` is probably an integer. Find the rows from that table for which the value of the FINAL-GRADE attribute is between 11 and 16.

In that same table `RESULT`, there is another attribute `C#`. An attribute with the same name appears in the table `CANDIDATE`. It is likely that `C#` is short for "Candidate Number", and so the `C#` that appears in `RESULT` is a *foreign key* that points back to a specific row ("tuple") in `CANDIDATE`. What is the value in that row of the "number and name" (name is likely the `C-NAME` attribute)?

Comment: amount of final grade >= 1

Answer (score 0):

you've just got the sql, try to read it in the reverse way.
Don't forget Restrict, Join, & Project.
Haha UTM Students :v
Cheers.

Comment: thanks but iam getting prob with the between operator